# How often are Rules Updates released for D&D 4th Edition?

Tags: dnd-4e

Dungeons and Dragons 4th Edition was released in mid-2008.  However, the [current list of Rules Updates](http://wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updates) only has one from October 2010.  Are updates really released that infrequently, or are there other places that updates are posted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updates seem to be about monthly. They list the most recent update as a unified package for all updated books, and keep an [archive](http://wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive) by book being updated.

Comment: They're taking a bit of a break around the Essentials launch, but otherwise, yeah, monthly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Rules Updates Archive](http://wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive) at the bottom of the Updates page.